# properly formatting/extracting JSON with date object within

Tags: json

I have a json file in which it contains information for a date (object) but i am having trouble formatting the file in order to extract information properly.

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "date": "new Date(1430539204557)",
    "score": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "new Date(1431144004557)",
    "score": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "new Date(1431748804557)",
    "score": 0
  }
]
```

even though this passes the json validation but when i am displaying this data in my page - instead of getting Sep 2015 Oct 2015 - it is showing "new Date(1431748804557)". Am i extracting the date data wrong?

```
this.dateDisplay = this.data.map(item => item.date);
```

Comment: @Andrius i haven't been able to get my code working with any of the suggested answer in that post.

Comment: @Andrius Just don't go by the title see and try to understand the use case...both are quiet different.

Comment: @bluePearl did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get each of the [date] values, you might need to use `eval()` (which is not safe) to serve these values as a 'method' or 'instantiating a new Date class'.

```
var aData = [
    {
        "date": "new Date(1430539204557)",
        "score": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "new Date(1431144004557)",
        "score": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "new Date(1431748804557)",
        "score": 0
    }
];

aData.forEach(function(oProperty) {
    var oDate = eval(oProperty.date);
    console.log(oDate); // Sat May 02 2015 12:00:04 GMT+0800 (PHT)
});
```

**Though it would be much better if you return your [date] value as the actual date values instead.** Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: adding `eval()` is not the safest choice ;)

Comment: Yes, that's why I place the following: 'Though it would be much better if you return your [date] value as the actual date values instead.'

Comment: Added note in your answer about eval() accept it and I will be able do remove my down-vote;

Comment: If i use the eval() could i get specific to how the date is displayed like: `May 2017` rather than the long detailed return?

Comment: Before I answer your concern, How do you get the json file in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As per the OP, `new Date(XXXXXXXXXXX)` is behaving like a string not an object.
- In `JSON`, just pass the `epoch time`(UNIX time) and then create the date while parsing the `JSON`.

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qwz1tw7a/)

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the double quotes for the date value.
Sample Code to generate the json file for processing:
https://jsfiddle.net/2epL7b6d/

```
var str = [{
"date": new Date(1430539204557),
"score": 0
},
{
"date": new Date(1430539204557),
"score": 0
},
{
"date": new Date(1430539204557),
"score": 0
}];
var fileStr = JSON.stringify(str);
console.log(fileStr);

saveFile('yourfilename.json', "data:application/json", new Blob([fileStr],{type:""}));

function saveFile (name, type, data) {
    if (data != null && navigator.msSaveBlob)
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([data], { type: type }), name);

    var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>");
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: type}));
    a.attr("href", url);
    a.attr("download", name);
    $("body").append(a);
    a[0].click();
    setTimeout(function(){  // fixes firefox html removal bug
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
    }, 500);  
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the json validator returns an error stating `Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`

Comment: still doesn't pass validation - `Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'`

Comment: Edited my answer with sample code. Please click the tick mark if you accept my answer. Thanks.